# How to fix the error "Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component." in next js

Tags: javascript, next.js

I want to fetch data from my data from firebase database with uesEffect hook but it gives an error message that
**Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component**.
How can i fix this any advice.Thanks in advance.
My  code is here

```
     useEffect(()=>{
            console.log("session",session)
        },[session]);
    
        const [myChats]=useCollection(db.collection('chats').where('users','array-contains',session.user.email));
    
        useEffect(()=>{
          myChats?.docs?.map((user)=>{
            setMyChat((prevState)=>[...prevState,user.id])
            useCollection(db.collection('chats').doc(id).collection('messeges').orderBy('timestamp','asc').limitToLast(1)).then(function(chat){
                console.log("chat",chat.id);
                setChats((prev)=>[...prev,chat]);
            })
        })
      },[myChats]);
        
       //   useEffect(()=>{
 // chats?.map((chat,i)=>{
 //     
 //        console.log("id",chat.id);
 //        console.log("photo",chat.data().photoURL);
 //        console.log("email",chat.data().user);
 //        console.log("chat",chat.data().message)
 //    })
 //    },[myChats])
         console.log("myChat",chats)
```

Comment: You're calling `useCollection` inside a `useEffect`, hooks should only be called in the top level of a component, and the same hooks should be called on every render cycle (no conditional hooks, or in your case a hook within another hook that won't always run).

Comment: Your Code is incomplete. Please provide all code.

Comment: @marioG8  complete code is not publishing

Comment: @pilchard should I use db reference